@azure/service-bus logs error "The amqp session * is open ? -> true"
I use nodejs package @azure/service-bus to send and receive messages to/from Azure service bus. It looks like everything works fine, but if I enable error logs I see following error multiple times whenever send or receive a message:
2024-10-08 16:57:45 -- close receiver explicitly 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.720Z rhea-promise:error [connection-4] The receiver '***e87' on amqp session 'local-1_remote-1_connection-4' is open ? -> true
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.720Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:1 -> detach#16 {"closed":true} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.752Z rhea:io [connection-4] read 17 bytes
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.752Z rhea:io [connection-4] got frame of size 17
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.752Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:1 <- detach#16 {"closed":true} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.752Z rhea:events [connection-4] Link got event: receiver_close
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.753Z rhea-promise:error [connection-4] The amqp session 'local-1_remote-1_connection-4' is open ? -> true
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.754Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:1 -> end#17 {} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.789Z rhea:io [connection-4] read 15 bytes
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.789Z rhea:io [connection-4] got frame of size 15
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.789Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:1 <- end#17 {} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.790Z rhea:events [connection-4] Session got event: session_close
2024-10-08 16:57:45 -- close client explicitly
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.790Z rhea-promise:error [connection-4] The sender '***bca' on amqp session 'local-0_remote-0_connection-4' is open ? -> true
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.791Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 -> detach#16 {"closed":true} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.816Z rhea:io [connection-4] read 17 bytes
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.816Z rhea:io [connection-4] got frame of size 17
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.816Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 <- detach#16 {"closed":true} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.816Z rhea:events [connection-4] Link got event: sender_close
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.817Z rhea-promise:error [connection-4] The receiver '***0b6' on amqp session 'local-0_remote-0_connection-4' is open ? -> true
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.817Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 -> detach#16 {"handle":1,"closed":true} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.843Z rhea:io [connection-4] read 18 bytes
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.843Z rhea:io [connection-4] got frame of size 18
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.843Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 <- detach#16 {"handle":1,"closed":true} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.844Z rhea:events [connection-4] Link got event: receiver_close
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.845Z rhea-promise:error [connection-4] The amqp session 'local-0_remote-0_connection-4' is open ? -> true
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.846Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 -> end#17 {} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.870Z rhea:io [connection-4] read 15 bytes
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.870Z rhea:io [connection-4] got frame of size 15
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.871Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 <- end#17 {} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.871Z rhea:events [connection-4] Session got event: session_close
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.871Z rhea-promise:error [connection-4] The connection is open ? -> true
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.872Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 -> close#18 {} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.897Z rhea:io [connection-4] read 15 bytes
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.897Z rhea:io [connection-4] got frame of size 15
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.897Z rhea:frames [connection-4]:0 <- close#18 {} 
2024-10-08 16:57:45 2024-10-08T14:57:45.897Z rhea:events [connection-4] Connection got event: connection_close

What does it mean and how to fix it?

Looks like normal flow when a receiver closes.   Not enough context to know if this is due to explicit closing or idle timeouts or transient network failures.   A code snippet demonstrating usage may help.

@JesseSquire, thank you for the answer. It happens when I close receiver and client explicitly and I don't have any functional problems with this. The only issue is that message is logged with "rhea-promise:error" label. If it's a normal flow, I would expect it to be logged not as an error.
The flow is following: create client and sender -> send message -> close sender -> close client -> create client and receiver -> receive messages -> complete messages -> close receiver -> close client.

Unfortunately, RHEA is a third-party library that the JS package uses as its AMQP transport.  I don't believe that the Service Bus library has control or influence over the logs that it emits, but I'll pass this feedback along and see what can be done.
